# Combine multiple images to form a strip of images ffmpeg

Tags: images, ffmpeg, combine

I wish to combine multiple images into a single strip of images, using FFMPEG.

I have been trying to search this thing on google, but unable to find anything useful. All links take me to places where multiple images are combined to give a video output.

Assuming that all the files are of the same width and height, how can I join them to get a single strip of images. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Number of images would be variable. It can range from 10 to several 100s.  And I want a horizontal strip.

Answer (score 22):

## Use the tile filter

[image: tile]

Using the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [tile](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) video filters with input files `001.png` to `005.png`:

```
ffmpeg -i %03d.png -filter_complex "scale=120:-1,tile=5x1" output.png
```

If you have file names that are in a non-numbered sequential order you can use the [glob pattern type](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) (not supported by Windows):

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -filter_complex tile=5x1 output.png
```

#### Margin / border

You can also add a margin (outer border space) and padding (space between frames):

[image: tile with margin and padding]

```
ffmpeg -i %03d.png -filter_complex "scale=120:-1,tile=5x1:margin=10:padding=4" output.png
```

Default color is black. Add the `color` option if you want to change the border/margin color:

```
ffmpeg -i %03d.png -filter_complex "scale=120:-1,tile=5x1:margin=10:padding=4:color=white" output.png
```

A vertical orientation is possible. `tile=1x5` for this example:

[image: vertical tile]

## More info

See the [tile filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile).

Comment: I'm using your command but the result I'm getting is (only first image is shown, all other are black): https://i.ibb.co/zPgPJ0V/Untitled.png

Comment: @user2988257 I can't duplicate that behavior. Provide a link to a pastebin that shows your full command and the complete console output.

Comment: @llogan If I have single image then How can I create tile from that?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya `ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i input.jpg -i input.jpg -filter_complex "[0][1][2]hstack=inputs=3" -vframes 1 output.jpg` See [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/)

Comment: how can i set the color of the padding to be white?

Comment: @Kong According to the [tile filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) use the `color` option: `ffmpeg -i %03d.png -filter_complex "scale=120:-1,tile=5x1:margin=10:padding=4:color=white" output.png`

Comment: I wanted to simply tile images together without reducing image quality and found this post. I modified it for my task using: ffmpeg -i %03d.png -filter_complex "tile=5x1" tiled.png      What a great function:  just by changing tile to untile you reverse the effect, and using 1x5 gives you vertical stitching.

Comment: Didn't work for me had to use hstack instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903609/3984575

Answer (score 5):

If you've *got* do it with `ffmpeg` then I don't know. If you want to get the job done and are willing to use another program suitable for the task then `convert` is part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

```
convert sepimage-0.png sepimage-1.png sepimage-2.png -channel RGB \
-combine imagecopy.png
```

Comment: The images need to be the same size, otherwise the output just creates duplicates of the images.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a job for ImageMagick, not ffmpeg! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737061/merge-images-side-by-side-horizontally