# Take the frames and put them together in one image with a single command

Tags: ffmpeg

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/625189/combine-multiple-images-to-form-a-strip-of-images-ffmpeg)  answer shows how i can glue the pictures into one.

Is it possible to take a certain amount of frames (for example 10) and put them together in one picture? With a single command.

Answer (score 1):

Your mentioning frames so i assume you mean frames from the same movie and you would like to use ffmpeg and lets also assume output would be jpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i <some-movie> -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,200)),tile=10x1" image.jpg
```

explanation:

- `frames 1`  from the manual: Stop writing to the stream after 1 frames.
- `select=not(mod(n\,200))` select every 200th frame.
- `tile=10x1` Make a filmstrip 10 images wide and 1 image height.

Change the selection and tile values to your needs.

Comment: `-frames x` means to output upto `x` frames and exit. Nothing to do with filter inputs.

Comment: Your right, changed the answer.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks! It is possible to somehow speed up the process? For example, using -ss before -i ?

Comment: Yes that would save some time. It might also skip images you need. Depending on the source codec and resolution i get roughly a 1 to 10 ratio. 10 minute movie takes 1 minute to create the filmstrip.